# Inverse Laplace transform of $ \frac{7s-6}{s^2-s-6}$

Tags: laplace-transform

IT is asked to find the inverse Laplace transformation of

$$\frac{7s-6}{s^2-s-6}$$

Writing it with partial fractions

$$\frac{7s-6}{s^2-s-6} =\frac{4}{s+2}+\frac{3}{s-3}$$

Ive found that the function that have this Laplace transformation is

$$4 \exp(-2t)+3\exp(3t)$$

But the given answer was

$$\frac{8}{3}\exp(2t)+\frac{13}{3}\exp(-t)$$

I can't see the equivalency. Maybe the answer is wrong .

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is correct.